# Free Source Code – Twitter Database Server: get_tweets.php

Tags: php

I have this PHP code to get tweets from tweet Database server but I have no idea how to execute.

I did the following steps and nothing happened.

1. I installed the WAMPserver.
2. I saved this PHP code in Notepad++
3. I launched it in firefox browser

Can anybody please try the code and let me know what the step that I missed?

the code:

http://140dev.com/free-twitter-api-source-code-library/twitter-database-server/get-tweets-php/

Thanks..

Comment: Did you save it with a file called something.php? in the www directory of wamp? Did you then navigate to `http://localhost/something.php` ?

Comment: Have you included the library referred to in the page?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're familiar with WAMP, but using this you need to make sure your php file is in the root of the Wamp.

(in this case the 'www' directory of WAMP).

I'm a mac user so I'm not very experience with Wamp but I hope this helped you a bit :-)

Comment: First: thank you second: have you tried the code on your mac?